# Filter applies for static and not dynamic (from JSON url retrieval) data in HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, min

I have created a table in HTML with static data and also retrieved data from a JSON file (url). I made the rows with the static data have a white background to make it easy to identify :

[image]

In the first column, there is an input box. The given value will multiply to the value of the second column and the result will appear in the 3d column.

Now, I added a filter at the top of the page but it only works for the rows with the static data. The link is here : [LINK](http://apolosiskos.co.uk/TEB/NOT2.html). I also created a snippet to make it easier to see the code. But the snippet would not work for the dynamically loaded data anyway due to the url (it contains https)

```js
$.getJSON(
     'http://apolosiskos.co.uk/TEB/MOCK_DATA.json',
     function(data){
         var tr;
         $.each (data, function (key, val) {
            tr = $('<tr/>');
            tr.append('<td class="stake"><input class="val1"/>' + '</td>');
            tr.append('<td class="odds">' + val.id + '</td>');
            tr.append('<td class="profit"><span class="multTotal">' +'0.00'+ '</span></td>');
            $('table').append(tr);
         });

       $("#counter-low, #counter-high,input").keyup(multInputs);
       });

function multInputs() {
    var mult = 0;

    $("tr").each(function () {
        var $val1 = $('.val1', this).val();
        var $val2 = $('.odds', this).text();
        var $total = ($val1 * 1) * $val2 - $val1
        $('.multTotal', this).text($total.toPrecision(3));
        mult += $total;
    });

    $("#grandTotal").text(mult);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('table').DataTable();
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
        return parseFloat(data[1]) >= parseFloat($('#counter-low').val() || data[1]) 
            && parseFloat(data[1]) <= parseFloat($('#counter-high').val() || data[1])
    });
    $('#counter-low, #counter-high').on('keyup', table.draw);
});
```

```css
h1{
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
table{
  width:100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.tbl-header{
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
 }
.tbl-content{
  height:300px;
  overflow-x:auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

th{
  padding: 20px 15px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
td{
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align:middle;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;

}

tr:nth-child(odd) td {
  background:#2cc3ce;
  color:#0d3852;
}

/* demo styles */

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,300,700);
body{
  background: #0d3852;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
section{
  margin: 50px;
}

input {
max-width:50px;
}

*,
*:after,
*::before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ac-custom {
 padding: 0 1em;
 max-width: 900px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.ac-custom h2 {
 font-size: 1em;
 font-weight: 300;
 padding: 0 0 0.5em;
 margin: 0 0 30px;
 color:#0d3852;
}

.ac-custom ul,
.ac-custom ol {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 800px;
}

.ac-custom li {
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0.5em 0;
 position: relative;
}

.ac-custom label {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 font-size: 1em;
 padding: 0 0 0 80px;
 vertical-align: top;
 color: #0d3852;
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.3s;
 transition: color 0.3s;
}

.ac-custom input[type="checkbox"],
.ac-custom input[type="radio"],
.ac-custom label::before {
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 top: 50%;
 left: 0;
 margin-top: -12px;
 position: absolute;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.ac-custom input[type="checkbox"],
.ac-custom input[type="radio"] {
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 z-index: 100;
}

.ac-custom label::before {
 content: '';
 border: 1px solid #0d3852;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
 transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.ac-radio label::before {
 border-radius: 50%;
}

.ac-custom input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label,
.ac-custom input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
 color: #fff;
} 

.ac-custom input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before,
.ac-custom input[type="radio"]:checked + label::before {
 opacity: 0.8;
}

/* General SVG and path styles */

.ac-custom svg {
 position: absolute;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -12px;
 left: 0px;
 pointer-events: none;
}

.ac-custom svg path {
 stroke: #0d3852;
 stroke-width: 13px;
 stroke-linecap: round;
 stroke-linejoin: round;
 fill: none;
}

/* Specific input, SVG and path styles */

/* Circle */
.ac-circle input[type="checkbox"],
.ac-circle input[type="radio"],
.ac-circle label::before {
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 margin-top: -15px;
 left: 10px;
 position: absolute;
}

.ac-circle label::before {
 background-color: #fff;
 border: none;
}

.ac-circle svg {
 width: 70px;
 height: 70px;
 margin-top: -35px;
 left: -10px;
}

.ac-circle svg path {
 stroke-width: 5px;
} 

/* Box Fill */
.ac-boxfill svg path {
 stroke-width: 8px;
} 

/* Swirl */
.ac-swirl svg path {
 stroke-width: 8px;
}

/* List */
.ac-list ol {
 list-style: decimal;
 list-style-position: inside;
}

.ac-list ol li {
 font-size: 2em;
 padding: 1em 1em 0 2em;
 text-indent: -40px;
}

.ac-list ol li label {
 font-size: 0.5em;
 text-indent: 0;
 padding-left: 30px;
}

.ac-list label::before {
 display: none;
}

.ac-list svg {
 width: 100%;
 height: 80px;
 left: 0;
 top: 1.2em;
 margin-top: 0px;
}

.ac-list svg path {
 stroke-width: 4px;
}

.row {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-top:0;
}
.col-sm-4 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-sm-4 {
    float: left;
  }

  .col-sm-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  } 
 
 .filter-columns {
 background-color:#2cc3ce;
 }
 
 .filter-columns-alt {
 background-color:#78D9E0;
 min-height:256px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

                <div class="col-sm-4 filter-columns-alt">
                    <form class="ac-custom ac-checkbox ac-cross" autocomplete="off">
      <h2>MIN - MAX</h2>
      Min:<input id="counter-low" type="text" /> &nbsp; 
      Max:<input id="counter-high" type="text" />
     </form>
                </div>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr id="ProductID" class="first">
            <th>A1</th>
            <th>A2</th>
   <th>A3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="txtMult">
            <td class="stake"><input class="val1"/></td>
            <td class="odds">2.2</td>
   <td class="profit"><span class="multTotal">0.00</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="txtMult">
            <td class="stake"><input class="val1"/></td>
            <td class="odds">2.2</td>
   <td class="profit"><span class="multTotal">0.00</span></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're initializing the plugin too early. This gets called before your ajax call has finished:

```
$('table').DataTable();
```

It's very apparent if you look at the markup. `even` and `odd` classes are only applied to first two columns and not the rest because they're added after the plugin has already been initialized.

[image]